# ASP.Net Core 6 WebApp: No default auth scheme with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i migrated my asp.net core mvc webapp from 5 to 6 and after that, windows auth was no more.
This problem only occurs when i try to debug my webapp in VS22. When i deploy it to IIS, win auth is working flawlessly. i have tried many suggested solutions to this problems, such as adding

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddNegotiate();
```

or

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

or

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
```

in various positions and orders in my Starup.cs.
I have also tried different hosting implementations (Kestrel, IIS).
I have also tried HttpSys where **it worked** but since i cant use it (company env requests IIS) i have to pass it unfortunately.
No matter which browser i use (FF, Chrome, IE, Edge) i always get the same 500 internal error response with this exception in the web app:

```
Exception thrown: 
'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll 
("No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. 
The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme)
or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).")
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup {
    private Config cfg;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
        this.cfg = new Config();
        Configuration.GetSection("appinfo").Bind(this.cfg);
        var client = new LoggingClient(cfg.GetAddressOf("Services.Api.Logging"), cfg.DisplayName.Split('.').Last());
        client.WriteLogAsync("UI starting", LogSeverity.Info);
        ReferenceHelper.TestReferences(cfg);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

        }).AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<Config>(options => Configuration.GetSection("appinfo").Bind(options));
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(provider => Configuration);
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(
            options => {
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
        //services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        //services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
        services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("InfoServices.Web.Administration")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(DefaultPaths.WEB_KEYSTORE))
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorLoggingMiddleware>(new LoggingClient(cfg.GetAddressOf("InfoServices.Api.Logging"), cfg.DisplayName.Split('.').Last()));
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        var supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "de" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[1])
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
        localizationOptions.ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders = true;


        //if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        //    //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        //} else {
        //    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        //}
        app.UseHsts();
        //app.UseAuthMiddleware();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Overview}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program{
    private static Config cfg;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cfg = ConfigJsonHelper.GetConfig();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                //webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                //{
                //    options.Authentication.Schemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                //    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                //    options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://" + LocalDataHelper.GetCurrentHostname() + ".domain.at:" + cfg.Port);
                //}).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                //{
                //    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                //    //config.Sources.Clear();
                //    config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                //    config.AddJsonFile("appinfo.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                //    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                //});
                //webBuilder.UseKestrel().ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                //{
                //    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                //    //config.Sources.Clear();
                //    config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                //    config.AddJsonFile("appinfo.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                //    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                //}).UseUrls("https://" + LocalDataHelper.GetCurrentHostname() + ".domain.at:" + cfg.Port);
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration().ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    //config.Sources.Clear();
                    config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                    config.AddJsonFile("appinfo.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                }).UseUrls("https://" + LocalDataHelper.GetCurrentHostname() + ".domain.at:" + cfg.Port);
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

For nuget pkgs i have:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="6.0.2" 
"jQuery" Version="3.6.0" 
"jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" Version="3.1.2" 
"jQuery.Validation" Version="1.19.3" 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="6.0.2" 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="6.0.0" 
"Microsoft.IdentityModel" Version="7.0.0" 
"Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" Version="3.2.12" 
"Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" 
"Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.5.3"
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60248",
      "sslPort": 6900,
      "windowsAuthentication": true,
      "anonymousAuthentication": false
    }
  },
    "profiles": {

        "Development": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you specify an authentication scheme. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916846/how-to-use-windows-authentication-on-asp-net-core-subpath-only

Comment: The web.config part did it, thank you very much. Must have overlooked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as suggested out by Chaodeng, i tried the attribute thing as suggestest in the link which did not do it for me. **However** i looked through the linked post ([How to use Windows authentication on ASP.NET Core subpath only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916846/how-to-use-windows-authentication-on-asp-net-core-subpath-only)) and i saw the usage of a mini web.config, only containing

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

which did it for me